# png to bmp in C#

Tags: c#, image, png, bmp

is there anyway that I can convert a png to a bmp in C#?

I want to download a image then convert it to a bmp then set it as the desktop background.

I have the downloading bit and the background bit done.

I just need to convert the png to a bmp.

Comment: If you're using Vista or Windows 7 they can deal with PNGs directly; no need to convert.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Image Dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png");
Dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: do i need to add any name spaces?

Comment: You will need to add references to System.Drawing.
And namespace System.Drawing.Imaging would be nice too

Comment: ImageFormat class located in the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace.

Comment: apparently those namespaces dont exist
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060600/what-namespaces-are-needed-for-this-piece-of-code-c

Answer (score 11):

Certainly. You'd want to load up a Bitmap object with your png:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("mypng.png");
```

Then save it:

```
myBitmap.Save("mybmp.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
Image imgFile = Image.FromFile(aFileName);
imgFile .Save(strOutFileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```