# what namespaces are needed for this piece of code? (c#)

Tags: c#

```
Image Dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png");
Dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

what the question says

i have these

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
```

but i get an error saying that the namespace drawing does not exist in the namespace system :/

Comment: Microsfot has a really good website called MSDN.  If you are using Visual Studio, F! is your friend.

Comment: Are you building from Visual Studio?

Comment: yes i am building from vs c# 2008

Comment: Go ahead and re-tag your question to include visual studio. Usually the more information you can provide about your environment will help the questions be found, and answered more directly. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Drawing

When you use `using` statements, this lets the compiler know that when you say `Image` you really mean `System.Drawing.Image` for example.

However, now the compiler needs to know where System.Drawing is. By default, in Visual Studio, you will probably already reference `System`, `System.Data`, and `System.Xml`.

Now you are writing for `System.Drawing`. Right-click the project in the project browser, and select "Add reference...". This will present you with a tabbed interface that lets you select one of:

- A .NET Reference. Any assembly in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) will be listed here. Scroll down and select `System.Drawing` for example.
- COM Reference. For interfacing with non-.NET, yet very Windows components.
- Projects. A Visual Studio nicety. Reference a DLL that has not been built yet. Select a project within the same solution. Intellisense before you compile.
- Browse (for a file). If a .NET component or other type with exported definitions has already been built, you can reference the DLL from here.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms is unnecessary here.

Comment: As an aside, I usually notice that I am not referencing the right DLL because my Intellisense won't be working. Have you found that you weren't getting a nice list popping up after typing `ImageFormat.` for example?

Comment: I have already referenced System.Drawing, but not able to import System.Drawing.Image any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "using" is only part of the equation.  You also have to reference the DLL which contains the code you want to use.

For example, if you write a cool library under the namespace com.shuttleu.awesomelib, I could have the following at the top of my C# file:

```
using com.shuttleu.awesomelib;
```

On its own, that won't do me any good, I have to reference the DLL (referred to as an "assembly") in my project.  You do that by right-clicking the project and selecting "Add Reference..."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the using statement, you also need to add the System.Drawing DLL (called an 'assembly') as a reference in your Visual Studio project. To do that, in the Solution Explorer pane usually at the right (if it's not open, go to View --> Solution Explorer), right click References and click Add Reference. In the .NET tab (open by default), scroll down until you see System.Drawing, select it, and click OK. After doing that, System.Drawing should appear under References in the Solution Explorer, and the using statement will now point to the correct DLL, therefore your code will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Adding the "using" is only part of the equation. You also have to reference the DLL which contains the code you want to use"

Just curious--why do we have to do both for a console app, while in an VB.Net web app, the text "Imports System.Drawing" is sufficient?