# How to convert PNG to BMP at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, image-conversion

I need to convert PNG file to BMP file on runtime.

I can't do it like

```
Image dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png"); 
dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

because i can't save the bmp image on the local disk as a file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save to stream

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Dummy.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Precise answer given [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060442/png-to-bmp)

```
Image Dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png");
Dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Since you don't want to follow this method, you can do it the way `Stecya` answered.
Just do it this way.

```
Stream stream;  
Dummy.save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp)
```