# Does making a Bitmap Transparent a smaller image, as in bytes

Tags: c#, optimization, graphics, bitmap

When building Bitmaps and collectively building a few Bitmaps and combining them into one Bitmap does it help to .MakeTransparent().

And or, before I send the Bitmap to the requesting client if I .MakeTransparent() will it become smaller in size? not width or height, buy in bytes?

In other words will .MakeTransparent() optimize the Bitmap, and if not does anyone get any suggestions on how to optmize a Bitmap before sending to the requesting client over the wire via internet?

The code in question is `sheet.MakeTransparent()`

```
 internal static Task<Bitmap> GetDoorSecheduleSheetAsync(ShopDrawing.DoorSchedules schedules, RotateFlipType rotate, byte schedulesPerSheet, byte currentI)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var sheet = new Bitmap(DrawingOptions.PAGE_HEIGHT_SIZE, DrawingOptions.PAGE_WIDTH_SIZE);
            sheet.SetResolution(150, 150);
            byte scheduleCnt = 0;
            float prevWidth = 0;

            using (Graphics dc = Graphics.FromImage(sheet))
            {
               dc.Clear(Color.White);

                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Black), 4))
                {
                    for (; currentI < schedules.Count(); currentI++)
                    {
                        if (scheduleCnt > 0)
                        {
                            dc.DrawLine(pen, prevWidth, 380/*need constant for start height*/, prevWidth, sheet.Height);
                        };

                        using (var doorSchedule = schedules[currentI].Door)
                        {
                            dc.DrawImage(doorSchedule, prevWidth + 50, 380/*need constant for start height*/);
                            prevWidth += doorSchedule.Width + 50;
                            scheduleCnt++;
                        }

                        if (scheduleCnt == schedulesPerSheet)
                        {
                            sheet.RotateFlip(rotate);
                            sheet.MakeTransparent();
                            return sheet;
                        }
                    };
                };
            };
            sheet.MakeTransparent();
            sheet.RotateFlip(rotate);
            return sheet;
        });
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the [**MakeTransparent** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzst10b.aspx) the bitmap will be converted to the [**Format32bppArgb**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) format, as this format supports an alpha channel.

The **Format32bppArgb** is a format what uses 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components. Therefore it could mean a change in size.

But just to have control over what really happens you could zip the bitmap or compress it bye converting it to other formats as PNG o JPG as **Alexei Levenkov** suggested

Here you can find and example of how to convert PNG to BMP, you can use the same code but exchanging formats

[How to convert PNG to BMP at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182178/how-to-convert-png-to-bmp-at-runtime)

Answer (score 5):

BMP is uncompressed format with essentially raw bytes (or palette indexes) for each pixel - there is no transformation that will change size of resulting file except changing bit-per-pixel count.

Don't send uncompressed bmp over network - use either loss-less PNG/GIF or (if it works for you) JPG.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great help! I do send the finial product as a .png over the wire. One of the things i was wondering about is how to compress these Bitmaps when I'm having to create three or four little Bitmaps to comprise on final bitmap, then i turn it into .png and send it to the client. Working with graphics is not an easy task but i've got the hand of it. I really would like to know if there is  an approach to when I'm building three or four bitmap parts to make one single Bitmap out of all the little parts.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Alexei Levenkov sending the raw BMP-Format over the wire is the ***worst*** choice.

Calling MakeTransparent() would (if it's not already the case) convert the image format to 32bit (= with alpha cannel), which is most byte hungry - transparency has its costs.

You should save the Bitmap as a i.e. **jpeg** (if you ***don't*** really need **transparency**) or **`png`** (if you really need it) - they're both **much more efficient**.

Look at this answered question about it: [High Quality Image Scaling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c-sharp)
It shows how to use the **.NET built-in image encoders**.