# How to convert image-type to bitmap

Tags: c#, image

I am making an application which works on `.BMP` and fixed size. I made the module for resizing but unable to convert `PNG`, `JPEG` and other picture formats to `.bmp`.

Is there any simple method, because of multiple compression schemes it is a lot difficult to write seperate module for each.

Comment: I cannot believe there are no questions on SO already addressing image conversion in C#...

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: Are you using the `Bitmap` class for this?

Comment: Thanx i think below is the required solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8327dd31-2db1-4daa-a81c-aff60b63fee6/)

```
public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

or use this

```
Image Dummy = Image.FromFile("image.png");
Dummy.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every image that you have already [loaded into memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) is independent from the source format. After manipulation you can write it back to disk by using [any format that is available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx) by simply calling the [`Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) method with the desired format

```
var bmp1 = Image.FromFile("myJpegFile.jpg");
bmp1.Save("c:\\button.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, please look at this question:

[Convert to BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060442/png-to-bmp)

and

[MSDN ImageFormat Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
using(Image img = Image.FromFile("image.png"))
{
    img.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap();
myBitmap.Save(, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

is the problem, that transparency in pgnsourcefilepathanme
is converted to black in bitmapdestfilepathname

Comment: Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pgnsourcefilepathanme);
myBitmap.Save(bitmapdestfilepathname, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

Comment: Please format code using the formatting tools.